# What is the use of comma operator in python iteables?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, syntax

[image: This is the question.]

Solution:

[image: This is the solution.]

Can anyone tell what is the use of , operator at the end of the 6th and 7th line?

Comment: this operator cast the value to a tuple, e.g.: `[], ==([],)` (means the list is inside of a tuple)

Answer (score -1):

The `,` there is not an operator, instead it is syntax for a literal of a tuple of a single element in the form `value,`.

Comment: It __IS__ an operator.

Comment: @DYZ It's no more of an operator than something like `[value]`, and doesn't call an operator method on the object for example.

Comment: i agree operator doesnt sound like the ideal naming for the character in that situation…

Comment: I take my words back. `,` is a delimiter https://docs.python.org/3.10/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators